# How to perform this operation using combined if and for statements

Tags: python

How do we combine a IF statement and FOR loop in python. Like

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
x = 4
count = 0
for i in list:
    if (i == x):
        count += 1
```

How do we combine lines 4, 5, 6 in a single line? Is this possible?

Comment: `len([i for i in list if i == x])`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it can be, what you are trying to do is count the occurences of number and Python List already has a method `count()` to get the job done. But You should refrain from using the variable name as `list` it would shadow the Python `list` data structure.

```
>>> number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print number_list.count(4)
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_count = sum(1 for i in number_list if i == x)
```

Do not use `list` or `count` as variable names since there could be confusion with the built-in meanings of those names. Terence Hill's answer is good but will use more memory if the list is long, since it builds a full list before finding its size. Mine is a generator expression and never builds the full list. ZdaR's answer is the most pythonic since it uses a built-in feature of Python and will probably be the fastest and use the least memory. This answer sticks the closest to what you actually asked.